# change "css" (in one component) based on some condition in other component? (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

There are two different components not related to each other,
is there a way to change "css" (in one component)  based on some condition in other component?

this two components belong to a hierarchy (same hierarchy) 
one component is at top of hierarchy  and other is bottom of hierarchy ,
on one condition in the component that is at bottom of the hierarchy is it possible to change css in the other component i.e at top

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you have stated in your question that you have change css of a component which is on the top of hierarchy on some condition by the lower most component in the hierarchy.

- First of all you have to send the state(or some flag or variable) from bottom most component to top most component. To do this, the better approach is to use `redux` which helps in state management and by using redux, you can able to communicate between these top and bottom component.
- Second, to change css, first you need to put all the css inline and then use the conditional operator to apply css based on the state of redux.

For example, I want to change the background color of this div according to the state of redux.

```
`<div style={ this.props.myVariable === true ? {backgroundColor: '#0f0f0f'}: null}></div>`
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to make all css inline, you can make two seperate class of css and apply css a according to the state of redux.

For example, i have two classes of css:

```
`a1 {
background-color: 'red'
}
b1 { 
background-color: 'green'
}`
```

and now i have to apply b1 class when my redux state changes

```
`<div className={ this.props.myVaribale === true ? 'a1' : 'b1'}></div>`
```

EDIT: typos